# Get related videos (by tags) and order by views in one query with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, inner-join

I've the following tables:

```
tag
id | name
1  | funny
2  | stack
3  | music

video
id | title         | thumbnail     | video
1  | first video   | thumb.png     | video1.mp4
2  | second video  | thumbnail.png | anothervideo.mp4
3  | third video   | woooow.png    | plssomeonehelpme.mp4

video_tag
id | id_video | id_tag
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 1        | 2
3  | 2        | 2
4  | 3        | 3

video_view
id | date                | id_video
1  | 2017-10-27 23:28:34 | 2
2  | 2017-10-27 23:38:04 | 2
3  | 2017-10-27 00:38:04 | 1
4  | 2017-10-28 10:38:04 | 1
5  | 2017-10-28 12:29:47 | 1
6  | 2017-10-30 15:39:33 | 3
7  | 2017-10-30 17:27:39 | 3
8  | 2017-10-30 00:22:54 | 2
```

And I want to get related videos (that have more mutual tags, and order by the number of mutual tags), and also get the number of views of that videos and order by views (if have the same mutual tags number, order by number of views).

So, I tried (assuming that the video `id` that I'm watching is `1`):

```
SELECT v.title, v.thumbnail, v.video, COUNT(v_t2.id) AS mutualTags 
FROM video_tag v_t 
INNER JOIN video_tag v_t2 ON v_t.id_tag = v_t2.id_tag 
INNER JOIN video v ON v_t2.id_video = v.id 
WHERE v_t.id_video = 1 AND v_t2.id_video != 1 
GROUP BY v_t2.id_tag 
ORDER BY mutualTags DESC
```

This code above return the wrong mutualTags, and I tried to get views anyway:

```
SELECT v.title, v.thumbnail, v.video, COUNT(v_t2.id) AS mutualTags, COUNT(v_v.id) AS views 
FROM video_tag v_t 
INNER JOIN video_tag v_t2 ON v_t.id_tag = v_t2.id_tag 
INNER JOIN video v ON v_t2.id_video = v.id 
INNER JOIN video_view v_v ON v_v.id_video = v_t2.id_video 
WHERE v_t.id_video = 1 AND v_t2.id_video != 1 
GROUP BY v_t2.id_tag, v_v.id_video 
ORDER BY mutualTags DESC, views DESC
```

But I get the wrong mutualTags and views number... So, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the above query execute without error? How did you group , it must throw an error

Comment: @Valli yes, without any error